# FileLog monitoring using python at a particular time period

Tags: monitoring, python-3.7, logfile

I want to monitor a logfile on server between 6 to 6:15 time period and need to check if a particular string is present or not in the logfile between that time. I want to hard-code it in my script.IF the string is not present I want to send an email to a particular person.
I am novice in Python.Any suggestions would be helpful.